# SonarQube for iOS vs Xcode code analysis

Tags: ios, xcode, sonarqube, static-analysis

I want to know if i should install sonarQube for iOS what are the pros and cons and is there a free version / trial that i can use.

Plus a guide how to set and use it properly.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SonarQube server and scanners are FOSS. They are written in Java, and so platform-independent.

To try them out, head over to the [downloads page](http://www.sonarqube.org/downloads/). Then check out the [documentation](http://www.sonarqube.org/downloads/) for how to get started.